# oscommerse 2.3.1 : Shipping Method

Tags: oscommerce

I want some thing like:

if the **total purchase** by a customer is **under $10** then s/he will charge **$3 Delivery/shipping cost** else if the **total purchase** by a customer is **over $10** then s/he will charge **free**

But under admin->modlues->shipping I saw:

**Shipping Cost**
The shipping cost for all orders using this shipping method.
***10:3.00,10.01:0.00***

Now I don't know what does that formula tells and how can I change this formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how table rate shipping is configured:

```
<up-to-amount>:<cost>,<up-to-amount>:<cost>...
```

what you have is, "up to 10, $3, up to 10.01, $0."

What you want is

10:3.00,1000000:0